# apt downgrade to a specific version of package (not present in repository)

Tags: apt, aptitude, gtk

I've got a system with `libgtk-3-0` version `3.22.30-1ubuntu1` installed. To fix a [known bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/945#note_111905) I want to downgrade to version `3.22.21`. However, running `aptitude` to find the available versions yells the following:

```
$ aptitude versions libgtk-3-0
package libgtk-3-0:
p  3.22.30-1ubuntu1                     bionic
i  3.22.30-1ubuntu2                     bionic-updates
```

so of course trying to install the version that I want didn't work

```
$ sudo apt install libgtk-3-0=3.22.21-1ubuntu1
E: Version "3.22.21-1ubuntu1" for "libgtk-3-0" not found
```

Comment: You could try adding an older repository. Then using Synaptic it is possible to force and lock an older version of Gtk. Warning! use at your own risk.

Comment: @theGtknerd what are the risks? Couldn't adding an older repository cause some trouble on other packages?

Comment: Yep, you're right. Commonly called dependency hell. I have used older repositories in some cases, and gotten them to work, but your milage may vary.